# PuTTy command script hangs after "chroot . sh"

Tags: ssh, script, putty, chroot, kitty

I'm trying to automate a build with Putty, just ssh'ing into a VM and running a few commands by specifying a `.txt` file that contains the commands to run.

One of my commands is `chroot . sh` and it looks like Putty just stops executing the rest of the commands at this point.  I'm not too familiar with why this happens, but is there any way to keep going after this point?  I have tried KiTTY as well, with the `-cmd` switch, but looks like the same thing.  I had read the `-cmd` switch in KiTTy is like inputting commands with keyboard but doesnt look like its working any better.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: What are you expecting the  ```chroot . sh``` command to do?

Answer (score 0):

`chroot . sh` reads like you're running an interactive shell, which would be waiting for the user to type a command.

To check, run the `.txt` file manually in the VM and see if execution also stops in this line.